# What is the best way to display pdf in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I need to display pdf documents within my iPad app, I've seen people suggesting loading it within a webview.

I want to know if this is the best\recommended way to display a pdf?

Comment: so far the UIWebView is the best way to display a pdf

Comment: For iOS 11+ PDFView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `QuickLook.framework` you can easly load pdf and disply i just add following easy step for load pdf using `QuickLook.framework`

- Add `QuickLook.framework` and import in to your class and set it's DataSource in to .h class `<QLPreviewControllerDataSource>`

**Use following method:**

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1;
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pdfFilePath]; // here is self.pdfFilePath its a path of you pdf
}
```

**and for load set Button Action:**

```
-(IBAction)LoadPdf
{
        QLPreviewController* preview = [[[QLPreviewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        preview.dataSource = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Found that viewing a pdf is actually rather simple, tried the above code and worked well. Do u my data sometimes being a url to the relevant pdf I was forced to go the webview route but would have preferred to use QLPreviewController

Answer (score 1):

Two easiest way to that

1. `UIWebView`
2. `QLPreviewController`

Comment: Apple will stop accepting submissions of app updates that use UIWebView APIs starting from December 2020. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.